# multisend ERC20 tokens

Tags: web3js

I have main address: `const fromAddress`

There is also an array of addresses and their keys:`foreth/keys`

I need to send all erc20 tokens from: `foreth` array to the: `fromAddress`

Tokens are sent only from the first address of the `foreth` array, a hash is generated for all subsequent addresses, which is not on etherscan with error: `Sorry, We are unable to locate this TxnHash`

It is necessary to make sure that tokens are sent from all addresses that are in the array `foreth`

```
let tokenAddress = "erc20_contract_addr";
let fromAddress = 'main_addr'
let privateKey = Buffer.from('key_main_addr', 'hex')

const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, tokenAddress)
let foreth = ["addr1", "addr2", "addr3", "addr4"];
let keys = ['addr1_key', 'addr2_key', 'addr3_key', 'addr4_key']

function nonce_addr(address) {
    return web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)
}

foreth.forEach(async function(recipient, i) {

    const balance = await contractInstance.methods.balanceOf(recipient).call(function(err, result) {
        let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, tokenAddress, {
            from: recipient
        })

        if (result < 0) return
        web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress)
            .then((count) => {
                let rawTransaction = {
                    'from': fromAddress,
                    'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
                    'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(21000),
                    'to': recipient,
                    'value': web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("0.0008")),
                    'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(count + i)
                }
                let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
                transaction.sign(privateKey)
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
                        .on('transactionHash', console.log)
                        .on('receipt', resolve)
                        .on('error', reject)
                })
            }).then(receipt => {
                console.log("eth was send")

                keys.forEach(async function(keys) {
                    let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(recipient, 'pending');

                    let rawTransaction = {
                        'from': recipient,
                        'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
                        'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(100000),
                        'to': tokenAddress,
                        'value': 0x0,
                        'data': contract.methods.transfer(fromAddress, web3.utils.toHex(result)).encodeABI(),
                        'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(nonce)
                    }
                    nonce++
                    let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
                    transaction.sign(Buffer.from(keys, 'hex'))
                    let serializedTx = '0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex')
                    return new Promise(resolve => {
                        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx)
                            .on('transactionHash', console.log)

                    })
                })


            })
    })

})
```

Comment: Your question is a total mess - both the description at the top and the code that follows. Please do a minimal effort to split this one long description into short readable sentences in separate lines. Then, please align your code properly.

Comment: @goodvibration I aligned the code

Comment: I fixed your description a bit. Still looks bad though. For example, couldn't you find a better way to write "I have address A = fromAddress and an array of addresses B (foreth)"? Or "hashes of transactions that are not on etherscan are created"? It's totally unclear in the language-aspect of it. Also, your code is way too long for the problem that you're describing. Try to include only the part which is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @goodvibration I edited the description and tried to leave only the problem part of the code

Comment: are you on a testnet?  If so, can you post the `rawTransaction`s - this might help get to the bottom of it?

Comment: @Zakalwe No( on mainnet, I posted all the code that I use, maybe this will help to figure it out somehow. The first part of the code sends eth to addresses and works correctly, and the second is actually problematic

Comment: @Zakalwe do u kknow how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

well, this:

`'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(count + k)`

is unlikely to work.  Each account has a separate nonce.  So, if all the accounts here had, say, nonce = 2, then each nonce would need to be 3, not 3, 4, 5 etc...

you can find the current nonce of an account using `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress)`

and then add one to it.  You need to do this for each address.

Note that this will not necessarily be accurate if there are pending transactions against the accounts.  Welcome to the wonderful world of managing Ethereum nonces!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I try to output nonce to the console, I get: Promise {<pending>}

Comment: And what is the best way to do this? Write a function that receives an address at the input and returns nonce?

Comment: I wrote a `nonce_addr` function that returns: `return web3.eth.getTransactionCount (address)` and replaced `web3.eth.getTransactionCount (recipient)` with `nonce_addr (recipient)`, but now, the first 2 addresses of the foreth array are processed fine, and 3 writes nonce too low

Comment: can you post your updated code?

Comment: yea, check now plz

Comment: I cant understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add **pending** flag to `getTransactionCount`.this flag also includes unconfirmed transactions in transaction count, which is important in your case.

I haven't tested but following code (roughly written) should work:

```
const testStackCode = async() => {
  let fromAddress = ''
  const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, contractAddress)
  let foreth = []
  let keys = []

  for(let i=0; i< foreth.length; i++) {
    let recipeint = foreth[i]
    let balance = await contractInstance.methods.balanceOf(recipeint).call()
    if(balance < 0 ) continue
    key = keys[i]
    let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(recipeint, 'pending');
    let extraData = contractInstance.methods.transfer(fromAddress, balance);
    let data = extraData.encodeABI()
    let txParams = {
      to: contractAddress,
      data,
      value: web3.utils.toHex(0),
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce)

    }
    console.log({ from: recipeint, to: fromAddress, nonce, amount: balance})
    var tx = new Tx(txParams)
    let privKey = _validatePrivKey(key)
    privKey = new Buffer(privKey, 'hex')
    tx.sign(privKey)
    let serializedTx = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex')
    await submitSignedTx(serializedTx)
  }
}

function _validatePrivKey(privKey){
  if(privKey.startsWith('0x')) privKey = privKey.substr(2)
  return privKey
}

const submitSignedTx = async(serializedTx) => {
  try{
    return new Promise((fullfill, reject) => {
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx)
        .on('transactionHash', txHash => {
         console.log(logmsg, 'transaction sent. hash =>', txHash)
          return fullfill({success: true, txHash : txHash})
        })
        .on('error', e => {
          console.log('unable to send tx', e);
          return fullfill({success: false, message: e})
        })
    })
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e)
    return {success: false, message: e.message };
  }
}
```

Comment: with ur part error:  `RangeError: private key length is invalid` at `transaction.sign(Buffer.from(keys, 'hex'))`

Comment: Remove 0x from private key

Comment: If I use 4 accounts, then the last account is ignored for some reason, and many nonce too low errors appear. I updated the code in question

Comment: can u help me? plz

Comment: Did you tried debugging the solution, checking when is nonce repeated? Go ahead with logging nonce, account and then you can know what is causing the issue. To replicate this I will need enough time to setup different contracts to check what's wrong. First thing to start with is to use synchronous for loop instead of for-each

Comment: It didn’t work through the for loop, all hope is for you

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. You have array of addresses (a1..an) in forEth variable and their private keys in anoher array(keys). There is an ERC-20 token (say X). You need to send X from `forEth` to a fixed address. If that's the case, I have updated the anser and you don't need nested for loop. Please update your question if that's not the case.

Comment: And can you add to the beginning of the code sending eth to foreth addresses, from a fixed address if their balance X is not empty? please

Comment: I tried to execute your code, but after starting nothing happens

Comment: What do u mean by nothing happens? Any error? You tried debugging?

Comment: There are no errors or notifications, I run the script, it runs and ends in a second.

Comment: The script can only end in seconds, if accounts don't have any balance. Try adding some consoles and check if it's not passing the `if(balance < 0 )`  block. I haven't added logs for cleanliness. Add logs, debuggers, put the whole code or specific code inside try-catch. Do a basic debugging man.

Comment: I inserted the string `console.log ("test");` after `const testStackCode = async () => {`and the script didn’t output anything, so it doesn’t enter this function

Comment: Then you are calling the fn properly. How you are executing the fn?

Comment: Did not understand you. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I defined all the variables and just ran the script with the node scriptname.js command, after which the script just exited

Comment: Putting in a script is fine. But you didn't called the function. At end of your script include `testStackCode().then(console.log)`. This way you'll execute the function

Comment: error on all transactions: `Returned error: transaction underpriced`

Comment: u know how to fix this?

Comment: As I understand it, it is necessary to increase the price of gas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102318/discussion-between-prashant-prabhakar-singh-and-ayurpwnz).

Comment: yea, i'm here..

Comment: can  u help me please?